# Merge [IP] with [IP-address]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

[ip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ip) and [ip-address](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ip-address) cover the same topic. Please merge them.

Comment: really?  Doesn't "ip" technically refer to the protocol (i.e. ipv4 and ipv6) rather than the actually address?